# Java exception with return

Tags: java, exception

```
public class TestException {

    int m1() {

        try {
            int i = 10, j = 0;
            System.out.println("s1");
            i = i / j;
            return 11;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("s2");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("s3");
        }

        System.out.println("s4");
        return 2222;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new TestException().m1());
    }
}
```

O/P:-

```
s1
s2
s3
s4
2222
```

Why is `s3` before `s4`?

Isn't `finally` called just before the method return?

What am I missing here?

Comment: "isn't Finally called just before method return?" - No.

Comment: Look at your code. Like really look at it. Where is your finally? Where is the returning return?

Comment: @ maroun: could you elaborate pls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, Flow of a try catch finally block

[image]

Comment: misconception understood..Thanks!

Comment: Nice painting. I'll try to keep that link in mind every time I think to myself "what is `finally` good for?"...

Answer (score 1):

> isn't Finally called just before method return?

[`Finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) is guaranteed to run  right after the execution of try catch block. Not at the end of the method.

In short it associated with `try-catch` Not to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be dividing any numbers by 0.  That seems to be the cause of the thrown exception.

finally() is called regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown, immediately after the try/catch block and before any other blocks.

Comment: He wants that *exception* to be thrown.